# How to calculate gasLimit for token transactions like USDT in BSC (BEP-20) blockchain?

Tags: node.js, smartcontracts, web3js, binance-smart-chain

I'm developing a DAPP in Binance Smart Chain and I'm wondering that how I can calculate the gas Limit for token transactions like USDT just like its Chrome extension that suggests the transaction gas Limit and calculate its transactionFee. I have a formula for calculating gas Limit in BNB transactions but that is not gonna work for token transactions.

Formula to calculate BNB Transaction:

```
const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice(); // estimate the gas price
    
const transactionObject = {
  from: SENDER_WALLET_ADDRESS,
  to: RECIEVER_WALLET_ADDRESS,
  gasPrice
}

const gasLimit = await web3.eth.estimateGas(transactionObject); // estimate the gas limit for this transaction
const transactionFee = gasPrice * gasLimit; // calculate the transaction fee
```

It would be great if I can calculate transactionFee like above, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing token transactions, you can instantiate the contract helper object in JS using [web3.eth.Contract](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html).

Then you can use the `.methods` property that contains helper functions based on the contract ABI and public functions.

And then you can chain the `.estimateGas()` function to the contract function.

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, contractAddress);
const gasLimit = await myContract.methods
    .transfer(to, amount)       // the contract function
    .estimateGas({from: ...});  // the transaction object
```

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You saved my day again  And I just recognize that the energy and bandwidth needed to do a contract transaction in the TRC20 blockchain is also unclear. Do you know a way to calculate them too ???

Comment: If the transaction is executing a contract function (on the TRC-20 contract), you can probably use the same snippet. I haven't verified it, but: Tron network uses a fork of the EVM and most of the RPC commands are the same (as in Ethereum), so `web3` should be able perform the `estimateGas()` on Tron network as well. You'll just need to use a Tron provider (in the `new Web3(provider)` constructor).

Comment: I have tested that but when I use usdt contract address in TRON network. it will give me this error `Provided address TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted`. And I have converted the address to hex and try again but nothing happened. but at least I find out that transaction in TRC20 got two options `29,631` and `14,631`  for energy and 345 for bandwidth.

Comment: `Web3.toChecksumAddress` may help

Answer (score -1):

Using Ethers.js Library

```
const ethers = require("ethers");

let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

let walletSigner = wallet.connect(provider);

let contractAddress = "";

const token = new ethers.Contract(
  contractAddress,
  contract_abi,
  walletSigner
);

let token_decimal = await token.decimals();

let token_amount = await ethers.utils.parseUnits(amount, token_decimal);


let gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();

gasPrice = await ethers.utils.formatEther(gasPrice);

let gasLimit = await token.estimateGas.transfer(
  receiver,
  token_amount
);

let transactionFee = gasPrice * gasLimit.toNumber();
```